# Make wait another method until coroutine finishes [Android Kotlin]

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

I want to make wait  method `getCurrentUser` or notify the method until the coroutine is finishes. Because variable `conversationKit` which is initialised in coroutine is used in method. Coroutine is launched inside the method `integrateConversationKit`.Both methods are invoking in `onCreate` in `MainActivity`. But I am getting the error lateinit property conversationKit has not been initialized.

```
    class ConversationKitService(private val context: Context) {
       private val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main)
       lateinit var conversationKit: ConversationKit
    
        fun integrateConversationKit() {
        
        
                val job = scope.launch {
                    val result = conversationKitFactory.create(
                        settings = settings
                    )
        
                    when (result) {
        
                        is ConversationKitResult.Success -> conversationKit = result.value
                        is ConversationKitResult.Failure -> println(result.message)
                    }
                }
        
        
            }
        
        
            fun getCurrentUser(): User? {
        
                return conversationKit.getCurrentUser()
            }
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you just make `getCurrentUser` a suspend function and call `integrateConversionKit()` from there? It doesn't seem like something to be called from `onCreate`.

Comment: Where are you calling `getCurrentUser` function?

Comment: Why I am not calling integrateConversionKit()  because variable conversationKit is required globally and need to call other suspend functions using this variable. So both this methods are invoked in onCreate

Comment: I'm unable to understand your usecase.

Comment: I agree with @OhhhThatVarun : if you want other methods to wait for the `conversationKit` variable to be initialized, you should just make `getCurrentUser` a suspend function itself and restructure the rest of the code to make that work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `Flow`s for updating the `conversationKit` reactively, then return it's first non-null value

```
 class ConversationKitService(private val context: Context) {
       private val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main)
       private val conversationKit = MutableStateFlow<ConversationKit?>(null)
    
       fun integrateConversationKit() {
                val job = scope.launch {
                val result = conversationKitFactory.create(
                        settings = settings
                    )
        
                    when (result) {
        
                        is ConversationKitResult.Success -> conversationKit.value = result.value
                        is ConversationKitResult.Failure -> println(result.message)
                    }
                }
        
        
            }
        
        
            suspend fun getCurrentUser() = conversationKit.first{ it != null }.getCurrentUser()
            
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just make the `getCurrentUser` a suspend call that fetches the `ConversationKit` from an internal suspend call that caches the result

```
   class ConversationKitService(private val context: Context) {
       @Volatile
       private var conversationKit: ConversationKit? = null

       ...

       suspend fun getCurrentUser() = getConversationKit()?.getCurrentUser() 

       private suspend getConversationKit(): ConversationKit? {
           if (conversationKit != null) return conversationKit
           val result = conversationKitFactory.create(settings = settings)
           conversationKit = when (result) {
               is ConversationKitResult.Success -> result.value
               is ConversationKitResult.Failure -> null           
           } 
           return conversationKit
       }          
   }
```

A `null` value then implies an error to retrieve the value. You could also wrap that in some kind of `Result` so that you return a success / failure rather than a nullable value.

If what you are really trying to do, though, is to make `getCurrentUser` a non-suspending *blocking call* that doesn't require a coroutine to use it then you could use `runBlocking`:

```
   class ConversationKitService(private val context: Context) {
       @Volatile
       private var conversationKit: ConversationKit? = null

       ...

       fun getCurrentUser() = runBlocking { 
           getConversationKit()?.getCurrentUser()
       }

       private suspend getConversationKit(): ConversationKit? {
           if (conversationKit != null) return conversationKit
           val result = conversationKitFactory.create(settings = settings)
           conversationKit = when (result) {
               is ConversationKitResult.Success -> result.value
               is ConversationKitResult.Failure -> null           
           } 
           return conversationKit
       }          
   }
```

I wouldn't really recommend this approach, though.